# Can't write to csv file at chosen frequency

Tags: python, csv, frequency, accelerometer

so I'm trying to store the data from an accelerometer (https://download.mikroe.com/documents/datasheets/asm330lhh_datasheet.pdf) into a csv file. I wanted to use it in maximum frequency @6667Hz, but it only writes in the csv file at about @3Hz. I don't know if the problem is in the code itself or if it's just impossible to write in csv files at such high frequency. Here is the code im using

```
def ASM330_start():     #configures accelerometer
    # Configure FIFO
    fifo3_config_sel = [0b00011010] # FIFO batch data rate @12.5Hz for gyro and @6667Hz for accel
    fifo3_indx = 0
    bus.write_byte_data(ASM330_ADDR, FIFO_CTRL3, int(fifo3_config_sel[fifo3_indx]))
    fifo4_config_sel = [0b00000110] # If the FIFO is full, the new sample overwrites the older one
    fifo4_indx = 0
    bus.write_byte_data(ASM330_ADDR, FIFO_CTRL4, int(fifo4_config_sel[fifo4_indx]))
    #Write to Gyro configuration register
    gyro_config_sel = [0b00010000] # byte registers @12.5Hz
    gyro_config_vals = [250.0] # degrees/sec
    gyro_indx = 0
    bus.write_byte_data(ASM330_ADDR, CTRL2_G, int(gyro_config_sel[gyro_indx]))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    #Write to Accel configuration register
    accel_config_sel = [0b10100000] # byte registers @6667Hz
    accel_config_vals = [2.0] # g (g = 9.81 m/s^2)
    accel_indx = 0
    bus.write_byte_data(ASM330_ADDR, CTRL1_XL, int(accel_config_sel[accel_indx]))
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # interrupt register (related to overflow of data [FIFO])
    return gyro_config_vals[gyro_indx],accel_config_vals[accel_indx]

def read_raw_bits(register):
    # read accel and gyro values
    high = bus.read_byte_data(ASM330_ADDR, register)
    low = bus.read_byte_data(ASM330_ADDR, register+1)

    # combine high and low for unsigned bit value
    value = ((high << 8) | low)

    # convert to +- value
    if(value > 32768):
        value -= 65536
    return value

def ASM330_conv():      #returns converted data from accel and gyro
    # raw acceleration bits
    acc_x = read_raw_bits(OUTX_H_A)
    acc_y = read_raw_bits(OUTY_H_A)
    acc_z = read_raw_bits(OUTZ_H_A)

    # raw gyroscope bits
    gyro_x = read_raw_bits(OUTX_H_G)
    gyro_y = read_raw_bits(OUTY_H_G)
    gyro_z = read_raw_bits(OUTZ_H_G)

    #convert to acceleration in g and gyro dps
    a_x = (acc_x/32768)*accel_sens
    a_y = (acc_y/32768)*accel_sens
    a_z = (acc_z/32768)*accel_sens

    w_x = (gyro_x/32768)*gyro_sens
    w_y = (gyro_y/32768)*gyro_sens
    w_z = (gyro_z/32768)*gyro_sens

    return a_x,a_y,a_z, w_x, w_y, w_z

def leracc():       #reads acc value
    while 1:
        global ax,ay,az,wx,wy,wz,acc, restart_script
        if restart_script:
            return
        ax,ay,az,wx,wy,wz = ASM330_conv()
        acc = True

t1 = threading.Thread(target=leracc)
t1.start()

while 1:
    if(luz):
        with open (aquire_folder + "acc.csv", 'a') as csvFileacc:
            writeracc = csv.writer(csvFileacc)
            while (contador < 1):
                writeracc.writerow(headeracc)
                contador = contador + 1
            if(acc):
                acc = False
                dataacc = [ax,ay,az,tempo]
                writeracc.writerow(dataacc)
            csvFileacc.close()
```

I know there are some variables I don't explain but I don't think they are neccessary to resolve my question.

Comment: Whatever's the bottleneck, you may be able to avoid it by writing the data into a memory-based file via an [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) — assuming you have enough memory anyway.

Comment: It looks as if you are opening a file, appending to it, and closing it again, repeatedly in a loop. My guess is that it is not the writing that is taking the time, but the repeated filesystem calls to find and open it.

Comment: @martineau but as I saw it will be treated as a file, is it still possible to print this string into a csv?

Comment: @BoarGules I open the file when I turn on the led I have with a push button ```if(luz)```so I believe that's not the problem. I might be wrong

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question what was controlling the loop.

Comment: @BoarGules Yeah, I didn't want to put the whole code here, but im basically using a GPS and an accelerometer+gyroscope and placing the gyro+GPS data onto a csv file and the accelerometer+GPStime to another csv file. Although I get frequency problems

Comment: You can turn the memory file into a real one by writing the data in it into the latter (via+ a single call to `write()`).